# Disable scroll on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have a simple HTML page where when I touch a div we can't scroll. You can find this page [here](http://bories.gg.free.fr/ftp//testChromeOverflow.html)

If you open this page with a desktop browser, like firefox, if you hold click down on the div you can't scroll.

Now I want this behaviour on mobile, like Android. In fact on Android if you open this page you can scroll in any cases.

Sorry for the colors in my examples ;)

Comment: I can scroll in both Chrome & Firefox

Comment: Keep the mouse click down and you won't be able to scroll

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are asking how to disable scroll on mobile devices:

You can add an event listener for `touchstart` and `touchmove`. Then when these events are triggered use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/download/#-fontface-backgroundsize-borderimage-borderradius-boxshadow-flexbox-hsla-multiplebgs-opacity-rgba-textshadow-cssanimations-csscolumns-generatedcontent-cssgradients-cssreflections-csstransforms-csstransforms3d-csstransitions-applicationcache-canvas-canvastext-draganddrop-hashchange-history-audio-video-indexeddb-input-inputtypes-localstorage-postmessage-sessionstorage-websockets-websqldatabase-webworkers-geolocation-inlinesvg-smil-svg-svgclippaths-touch-webgl-shiv-cssclasses-addtest-prefixed-teststyles-testprop-testallprops-hasevent-prefixes-domprefixes-load) to detect whether the browser is a touch device. Obviously not all mobiles are touch devices and there are touch devices that have high resolution so feel free to add or to the if statement.

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', this.touchstart);
document.addEventListener('touchmove', this.touchmove);

function touchstart(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
}

function touchmove(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
}
```

Or, just use Modernizr and then use CSS:

```
html.touch body {
     overflow:hidden;
}
```

And then add media-queries to effectively have your or statements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, events touchstart and touchmove work well, but the preventDefault method doesn't works. The CSS code with Modernizr doesn't works too. I updated my code for you can test on your mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to turn my mobile scroll off by simply adding:

```
html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
}
```

Its important to use `%` not `vh` for this.