# Disabling animation ScrollTo only in tablets and mobiles?

Tags: jquery, scrollto

How can I do to disable the animation ScrollTo only in tables and mobiles? 
My code is as follows:

```
$('a.scrollto').click(function (event) {
    $('html, body').scrollTo(this.hash, this.hash, {gap: {y: -70}, animation:  {easing: 'easeInOutCubic', duration: 1700}});
    event.preventDefault();

    if ($('.navbar-collapse').hasClass('in')) {
        $('.navbar-collapse').removeClass('in').addClass('collapse');
    }

});
```

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17728948/3509874

Comment: I was unable to solve it, Maybe it is easier to remove ScrollTo from <li> class when screen smaller than 768px, but I do not know HOWTO. 
My button is as follows:
    
<li><a href="#section-home" title="Home" class="scrollto">Home</a></li>

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to solve it, Maybe it is easier to remove ScrollTo from `<li>` class when screen smaller than 768px, but I do not know HOWTO. My button is as follows:

```
<li><a href="#section-home" title="Home" class="scrollto">Home</a></li>
```